# Search a List inside another with IQueryable

Tags: entity-framework, lambda

```
    public static IQueryable<Institution> WithFunds(this IQueryable<Institution> query, IEnumerable<Fund> allowedFunds)
    {
        return query.
    }
```

I want to get the query to return all Institutions having any of the Fund given in 'allowedFunds' list in Institution.Funds. Please help.

My class hierarchy goes like this.

```
   public partial class Institution 
   {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Fund> Funds { get; set; }
   }

   public partial class Fund
   {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual Institution Institution { get; set; }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Contains` query:

```
Fund[] funds = allowedFunds.ToArray();
return query.Where(x => x.Funds.Any(f => funds.Contains(f)));
```